# Gsub for non-numeric characters is removing numeric characters as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Code:

```
puts "params[:phone] is " + params[:phone]
ph = params[:phone].gsub!(/\D/,'')
Rails.logger.info("ph is now " + ph + "\r\n")
```

Rails console:

params[:phone] is 808XXXXXXX <-- (REDACTED FOR PRIVACY)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2383ms

TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  app/controllers/api_controller.rb:400:in `+'

That means that 'ph' is nil.

Wut?

That same gsub!(/\D/,'') part has been working fine for nearly a year, stripping hyphens, spaces, parentheses, etc.

Now it wants to completely strip everything.

I don't get it.

EDIT:

When I use this:

```
ph = params[:phone].gsub(/\D/,'')
```

I get the result that I expect, both with and without digits (eg. "8084445555" or "808-444-5555" I get the result "8084445555")

But I still want to know why.  gsub! is going to replace params[:phone], I get that, but it *should not* be stripping non-numerics, and it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer:

`gsub` will return the original string if it doesn't match anything. On the other hand, `gsub!` will return `nil` in such case.

If both methods match, they will return the string with the substitutions in place and there is nothing special about it, except that `gsub!` will modify the receiver object as you should already know.

Here are some examples that illustrate the facts. Pay special attention to the subjects and the returned values. You can try the following in **irb** if you want.

```
phone_number = "888-555-0110"              #=> "888-555-0110"
stripped_pn = phone_number.gsub(/\D/, '')  #=> "8885550110"
phone_number                               #=> "888-555-0110"
stripped_pn.gsub(/\D/, '')                 #=> "8885550110"
```

Here are the same examples with `gsub!`:

```
phone_number = "888-555-0110"               #=> "888-555-0110"
stripped_pn = phone_number.gsub!(/\D/, '')  #=> "8885550110"
phone_number                                #=> "8885550110"
stripped_pn.gsub!(/\D/, '')                 #=> nil
```

Comment: I did not know that gsub! would return a nil string in this manner.  Thank you.